# show that if ~ is a congruence on a ring $R$, then the equivalence class of $0$ is an ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

show that if ~ is a congruence on a ring $R$, then the equivalence class of $0$ is an ideal of $R$

Im not sure where to start here. when we did groups the congruence ~ was defined as if $H \le G$ then $a \sim b$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$

Comment: There is something missing in this question. The definition of "congruence" you are citing is not the one that is used in the problem.

Comment: I know thats the issue, Im not given a definition. and I couldn't find a general definition.

Comment: Unfortunately "congruence" is not a standard notion, so it's a matter local to the class you are taking or the book you are reading.

Comment: I found a relation ~ on a set A is called compatible with an operation * if whenver a~b and $c \in A$ then a*c~b*c and c*a~c*b. A relation ~ on a ring R is called a congruence relation, if it is an equivalence relation on R and is compatible with $+$ and $\cdot$

Comment: Hint: show that $a \sim b \iff a - b \in [0]_{\sim}$ first. This will show the equivalence class of $0$ is an abelian subgroup of $(R,+)$, and now you just have to prove the "absorption conditions" of an ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sim$ be a congruence on $R$ and let $[0]=\{r\in R: 0\sim r\}$.

1. $0\in [0]$ because $\sim$ is reflexive.
2. Suppose $0\sim r$ and $0\sim s$; then $(0+0)\sim(r+s)$, so $r+s\in[0]$.
3. Suppose $0\sim r$; then, since $-r\sim -r$, we have $(0-r)\sim(r-r)$ and so $-r\sim 0$, so $-r\in[0]$.
4. Suppose $0\sim r$ and $s\in R$. Since also $s\sim s$, we have $0s\sim rs$ and $s0\sim sr$, so $rs\in[0]$ and $sr\in[0]$.

We have of course used that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and that $a\sim b$ and $c\sim d$ imply $a+c\sim b+d$ and $ac\sim bd$.

Comment: and to show the absorbing: $0s \sim rs \implies 0 \sim rs$ ??

Comment: @oliverjones In a ring $0r=0$ for all $r$. It's in the first page of ring theory.

Comment: yeah I understand that. But your answer doesn't explicitly say anything about the absorbing aspect. So I was curious if thats how I would explicitly say that.

Comment: tried tagging you but wont let me for some reason

Comment: @oliverjones What absorbing are you referring to? Item 4 shows that, for all $r\in[0]$ and all $s\in R$, we have $rs\in[0]$ and $sr\in[0]$, which is the required property for being an ideal.

Comment: I guess it was exactly that. thanks for your help!

Comment: @oliverjones Next exercise: if $I$ is an ideal and we define $x\sim y$ for $x-y\in I$, then $\sim$ is a congruence on $R$ and $[0]=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've somewhat figured it out.

Let $\sim$ be a congruence relation on $\langle R, + , \cdot \rangle$ and $S = [0]_{\sim}$

$0 \in S, S \neq \emptyset$

$0 \sim 0$

Let $x,y \in S$ then,

if $0 \sim x, 0 \sim y$ then $0+0 \sim x+y$ and $0 \cdot 0 \sim x \cdot y$ $S$ is closed

and $0 \sim x \implies 0^{-1} \sim x^{-1}$ but $0=0^{-1}$ thus $0 \sim x^{-1}$ inverses exist in $S$

further,

$0 \sim y \implies  0 - x  \sim y - x$, and $ \implies x- 0 \sim x-y \in S$  thus $\langle S, + \rangle \le \langle R, + \rangle$

$0 \sim y \implies 0 \cdot x \sim y \cdot x \implies 0 \sim y \cdot x$

That's probably a pretty rough start but maybe on the right track?

Comment: What's $0^{-1}$? Don't confuse multiplication with addition! $x^{-1}$ doesn't necessarily exist in a ring.

Comment: its just $0$ showing the $0$ is its own inverse to show $0 \sim x^{-1}$